# Pick up whatever has been entered in Text Box in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like some code which can:

Pick up a number that has been entered in a text box in a user form.

The text box is called `Height`

Thanks

Comment: have a look at some of the properties you get with Intellisense and see if any of those look like a property that would hold the Text of a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value from the text box like this.

```
Dim heightInput = Height.text
```

However, you should do some validation before assuming it is a valid number.

such as

```
Dim validHeight as Integer
If int.TryParse(heightInput, validHeight) then
' Put code here
End If
```

for more
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets1p14.html

Comment: I'm mostly a C# developer.  So I might have/give a mistake or 2 in my VB.  Is the Height exactly how the textbox name is spelled?

Comment: VB is case insensitive, but VBA (by default) is case Sensitive.  the Name of your text box is height, not Height, try a lower case h in the code.

Comment: do you know it's still that line?  Also where is heightnumber defined?

Comment: The error suggests you there is a problem with HeightNumber, is it a private or dim somewhere else?  (Also a good practice is to append 'txt' to the front of the name for all text boxes as a naming convention)

Comment: That one is easy.  You are not updating the value in the text box.  Look at what you are doing in Yes click and no click  you update it on the changes. (And I would love to have this marked as accepted!)

Comment: I don't think it's against the rules, though I'm not sure I'm comfortable yet putting my email out there.  I was looking for a way that you could point out your new questions but StackOverflow is so paranoid people will be answering questions in private they don't have a way to nudge someone to a question.